# Show custom image on a coordinate depending on zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display custom images on Google Maps depending on the zoom level.
Already checked here for answers, but I can't get it to work properly.

When the page is loaded for the first time (zoom level 3), the image is displayed while I used zoom<=4. But when I zoom in en out, the image disappears suddenly on zoom level 3.

So it kinda works, only for the part when you load the page for the first time in your browser.

```
var seamarker, i;
var seamarkers = [];
var locations = [
[53.473190, -31.504191, 'image2.png'],
[32.473190, -31.504191, 'image3.png']
];
/* Get the markers from the array */
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
seamarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]), 
     map: map,
     visible: true, // or false. Whatever you need.
     icon: locations[i][2],
     zIndex: 10

});
seamarkers.push(seamarker); // save all markers
}

/* Change markers on zoom */
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
zoom = map.getZoom(); 
if (zoom <= 4) {
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
seamarkers[i].setMap(null);
}
} else {
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
seamarkers[i].setMap(map);
}
}
});
```

below is the code voor Google

```
function initializeMaps() {
var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.914164,12.469482),
    zoom: 3,
    zoomControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    draggable : true,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
```

Answer (score 0):

You initially will see both markers, because both markers are visible.

When you zoom in or out the zoom_changed-event will fire and your code currently will either:

- zoom>4:show both markers
- zoom<=4: hide both markers

when you want to draw only a single marker, but with position/icon depending on the zoom-level create only a single marker and set the options icon/position when the zoom changes:

```
    //create a single "blank" marker
    seamarker = new google.maps.Marker({zIndex: 10});

    //apply the listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
      var i=(this.getZoom()<=4)?0:1;
      seamarker.setOptions({ map:this,
                             icon:locations[i][2],
                             position:new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0],
                                                             locations[i][1])})
    });

    //trigger the event to draw the initial marker
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'zoom_changed');
```